# How to find empty tables in hive database

Tags: mysql, hive

I have a hive database records with 50 tables;

I want to check if any tables are empty.

The database name is employee.

I don't want to do this manually i.e Do a select * query on each table individually.

Can anyone explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive does not keep track of the number of records present in a table. Only during the query execution, the files belonging to the particular table is read and processed. So there is no other way to know the number of records present in each table without querying each table individually.

Alternatively, You can run a disk usage command on the database directory in HDFS

`hdfs dfs -du -s -h <hive.warehouse.dir>/employee/*`

the table folders with **0B** are obviously empty.

This is possible because Hive stores the table files in the HDFS `LOCATION` given at the time of table creation or at the path mentioned for `hive.warehouse.dir` property in `hive-site.xml`. Default is `/user/hive/warehouse`.

If the tables are a `managed` tables, for the database `employee` all the tables' records will be stored under `<hive.warehouse.dir>/employee/`.

Comment: thank you @franklinsijo that was exactly what I was looking fro